# Saving RTF with image from RichEditBox to file

Tags: .net, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have a problem with saving RTF from RichEditBox. If RichEditBox contains an image, then saved RTF file contains unreadable data. I used method *Document.SaveToStream()* to save a data to file. Also saved file contains unknown control word **objblob**. For inserting image to RichEditBox, I used method *Document.Selection.InsertImage()*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received answer for my question [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/fd5e4f6e-3613-47bf-b57c-2aa19991e94d).

Comment: Can you look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30505735/wp-8-1-richeditbox-images-are-not-getting-saved-to-the-local-storage. I've kind of same problem,image saved into .rtf file is not loading in the app